# copyWith() method for Inheritance class on dart

Tags: flutter, dart, oop

I want to implement `copyWith()` method for my class. Since its inhirited class, i got error:

> The member being overridden.

[image]

my basemodel

```dart
class BaseData {
  int id;
  String? createdAt, updatedAt;

  BaseData({this.id = 0, this.createdAt, this.updatedAt});
  BaseData copyWith({
    int? id,
    String? createdAt,
    String? updatedAt,
  }) =>
      BaseData(
          id: id ?? this.id,
          createdAt: createdAt ?? this.createdAt,
          updatedAt: updatedAt ?? this.updatedAt);
}
```

and I have another class that extend to my `BaseData` model

```
class QcData extends BaseData{
  String name;
  QcData ({this.name =""});

  @override
  QcData copyWith({
  String? name
  }){
    return QcData(name: name ?? this.name);
 }
}
```

How to create `copyWith()` method for my model class?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

inheritance means that a class member's definitions should remain the same when you extend, or implement a base class, in your case by doing the:

```
  @override
   QcData copyWith({
   String? name
  }){
     return QcData(name: name ?? this.name);
 }
```

this method declaration is not the same as the `BaseData`'s since they take different sets of arguments, you should remain the arguments the same as the `BaseData`, so your code should be this in order to work:

```
class QcData extends BaseData {
  String name;
  QcData({this.name = ""});

  @override
  QcData copyWith({
    int? id,
    String? createdAt,
    String? updatedAt,
  }) {
    return QcData(name: name ?? this.name);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

We also need to pass data on while creating QcData(child). I prefer modifying constructor this way.

```dart
  const QcData({
    this.name = "",
    super.id,
    super.createdAt,
    super.updatedAt,
  });
```

Now we have access on copyWith method these property, another cause is I like to use `const` constructor with final fields.

```dart
 @override
  QcData copyWith({
    String? name,
    int? id,
    String? createdAt,
    String? updatedAt,
  }) {
    return QcData(
      name: name ?? this.name,
      id: id ?? this.id,
      createdAt: createdAt ?? this.createdAt,
      updatedAt: updatedAt ?? this.updatedAt,
    );
  }
```

The models will be

```dart
class BaseData {
  final int id;
  final String? createdAt;
  final String? updatedAt;

  const BaseData({this.id = 0, this.createdAt, this.updatedAt});

  BaseData copyWith({
    int? id,
    String? createdAt,
    String? updatedAt,
  }) {
    return BaseData(
      id: id ?? this.id,
      createdAt: createdAt ?? this.createdAt,
      updatedAt: updatedAt ?? this.updatedAt,
    );
  }
}

class QcData extends BaseData {
  final String name;

  const QcData({
    this.name = "",
    super.id,
    super.createdAt,
    super.updatedAt,
  });

  @override
  QcData copyWith({
    String? name,
    int? id,
    String? createdAt,
    String? updatedAt,
  }) {
    return QcData(
      name: name ?? this.name,
      id: id ?? this.id,
      createdAt: createdAt ?? this.createdAt,
      updatedAt: updatedAt ?? this.updatedAt,
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's a pattern I came up with that seems to work pretty well:

```dart
class BaseData {
    final int baseValue;

    BaseData([Map map = const {}, BaseData? data]) :
        baseValue = map['baseValue'] ?? data?.baseValue ?? 0;

    T copyWith<T extends BaseData>(Map map) {
        return BaseData(map, this) as T;
    }
}

class ExtendedData extends BaseData {
    final int extendedValue;

    ExtendedData([super.map, ExtendedData? super.data]) :
        extendedValue = map['extendedValue'] ?? data?.extendedValue ?? 0;

    @override
    T copyWith<T extends BaseData>(Map map) {
        return ExtendedData(map, this) as T;
    }
}
```

One thing to notice with the above however is that since we assign to a member using the construct `map[key] ?? defaultValue` we can't easily clear a value.

So a bit of additional code I use says, "if the key exists in `map`, unconditionally set its value." This lets us put a key with a null value in the `map` parameter dictionary and use that to clear a field.

Updated with this functionality I add the following:

```
extension MapExtension on Map {
    T? valueOf<T>(Object key, [Object? defaultValue]) {
        return containsKey(key) ? this[key] : defaultValue;
    }
}
```

Then the constructors change to:

```
    BaseData([Map map = const {}, BaseData? data]) :
        baseValue = map.valueOf('baseValue', data?.baseValue ?? 0);
```

and

```
    ExtendedData([super.map, ExtendedData? super.data]) :
        extendedValue = map.valueOf('extendedValue', data?.extendedValue);
```